# How to get a child view from fragment in my activity?

Tags: android, fragment

Well , when I was trying to get a webView from a fragment in my activity,it doesn't works.My code below:

```
WebView webView;
webView = (WebView) getFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_goods_details).getView()
                .findViewById(R.id.goods_details);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, this is a bad idea. Since a fragment has it own life-cycle. 
In your activity, you can control your fragment to add it/replace it but you won't know exactly when your fragment is ready for manipulating.

Rather than that, you can have support from [Event Bus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) or RxAndroid to dispatch event asyn to your Fragment from your activity. Within the fragment, then you can safely handle action/data/state of your webview

Comment: OH! My activity extends RoboFragmentActivity ,and I use a ViewPager to handle my fragments.Now ,I've no ideas to do this.

Comment: What would you want to do with the `webView` you obtain from that fragment? @SimbaLiu

Comment: to load a html5,and let html5 call a methed in android

Comment: ic, consider haveing a mechanism like Event Bus or RxAndroid for handling rather than access directly from your activity to fragment. At some point, your app may access the fragment when it's not ready.

Comment: Thanks,I need to recoding my code,and find another way to solve my task.

Answer (score 0):

```
YourFragmentClass {
    WebView webview;
    public WebView getWebview(){ return webview;}
}
```

In your activtiy:

```
Fragment f = getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(xxxx);
if(f instanceOf YourFragmentClass) {
    webView = (YourFragmentClass)f.getWebview();
}
```

Comment: it post a NullPointerException,my god